PHP MySQL Data Insertion from Excel Not Executing as Expected
I have a PHP script that reads data from an Excel file and inserts it into a MySQL database. The script reads the data correctly and performs the initial insertion into the tb_konsultasi table without issues. However, the subsequent insertion into the tb_detailrusak table based on conditions in the Excel data does not execute as expected.
Below is my complete code:
require_once 'includes/connect.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;

// Mengaktifkan pelaporan error
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function log_and_echo_error($message) {
    error_log($message);
    echo $message . "<br>";
}

if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    if (!is_dir($target_dir)) {
        mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $reader = new Xlsx();
        try {
            $spreadsheet = $reader->load($target_file);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            log_and_echo_error("Error loading spreadsheet: " . $e->getMessage());
            die("Error loading spreadsheet");
        }
        $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

        $koneksi = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME);
        if ($koneksi->connect_error) {
            log_and_echo_error("Connection failed: " . $koneksi->connect_error);
            die("Connection failed: " . $koneksi->connect_error);
        }

        $header = $sheetData[1]; // Simpan header untuk referensi nama atribut
        foreach ($sheetData as $index => $row) {
            if ($index === 1) continue; // skip header row

            if (!empty(array_filter($row))) {
                $tanggal_raw = $row['A'];
                $nama_perangkat = $row['B'];
                $nama_pelanggan = $row['C'];
                $kerusakan = $row['AM']; // Column containing kerusakan information

                // Konversi format tanggal ke YYYY-MM-DD
                $tanggal = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $tanggal_raw)));

                // Simpan data konsultasi
                $stmt_konsultasi = $koneksi->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_konsultasi (tanggal, nama_perangkat, nama_pelanggan, hasil_kerusakan) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                if (!$stmt_konsultasi) {
                    log_and_echo_error("Prepare failed for konsultasi: " . $koneksi->error);
                    continue;
                }
                $stmt_konsultasi->bind_param("ssss", $tanggal, $nama_perangkat, $nama_pelanggan, $kerusakan);
                if (!$stmt_konsultasi->execute()) {
                    log_and_echo_error("Execute failed for konsultasi: " . $stmt_konsultasi->error);
                    continue;
                }
                $id_konsultasi = $stmt_konsultasi->insert_id;
                $stmt_konsultasi->close();

                // Simpan detail kerusakan berdasarkan gejala
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    if ($key > 'C' && $key < 'AK' && $value == 'Ya') {
                        $nama_atribut = $header[$key]; // Ambil nama atribut dari header
                        $stmt_atribut = $koneksi->prepare("SELECT id_atribut FROM tb_atribut WHERE nama_atribut = ?");
                        if (!$stmt_atribut) {
                            log_and_echo_error("Prepare failed for atribut: " . $koneksi->error);
                            continue;
                        }
                        $stmt_atribut->bind_param("s", $nama_atribut);
                        if (!$stmt_atribut->execute()) {
                            log_and_echo_error("Execute failed for atribut: " . $stmt_atribut->error);
                            continue;
                        }
                        $result_atribut = $stmt_atribut->get_result();
                        if ($result_atribut->num_rows > 0) {
                            $atribut = $result_atribut->fetch_assoc();
                            $id_atribut = $atribut['id_atribut'];
                            $stmt_detail = $koneksi->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_detailrusak (id_konsultasi, id_atribut) VALUES (?, ?)");
                            if (!$stmt_detail) {
                                log_and_echo_error("Prepare failed for detailrusak: " . $koneksi->error);
                                continue;
                            }
                            $stmt_detail->bind_param("ii", $id_konsultasi, $id_atribut);
                            if (!$stmt_detail->execute()) {
                                log_and_echo_error("Execute failed for detailrusak: " . $stmt_detail->error);
                                continue;
                            }
                            $stmt_detail->close();
                        } else {
                            log_and_echo_error("Atribut not found: " . $nama_atribut);
                        }
                        $stmt_atribut->close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $koneksi->close();
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'Success',
            'message' => 'Data berhasil diimpor!'
        ));
    } else {
        log_and_echo_error("Failed to move uploaded file.");
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Failed to move uploaded file.'
        ));
    }
} else {
    log_and_echo_error("No file selected.");
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'Error',
        'message' => 'No file selected'
    ));
}

Issues:
The initial insertion into tb_konsultasi works fine.
The subsequent insertion into tb_detailrusak based on specific conditions does not work as expected.
**What I have tried:
**
Added error logging and echo statements to debug the issue.
Verified that the conditions for inserting into tb_detailrusak are met.
Ensured that the database connection is successful and the initial insertion into tb_konsultasi works.
Checked if tb_atribut contains the relevant data for nama_atribut.
Database Schema:
tb_konsultasi: id_konsultasi (AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY), tanggal, nama_perangkat, nama_pelanggan, hasil_kerusakan
tb_detailrusak: id_detailrusak (AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY), id_konsultasi, id_atribut
tb_atribut: id_atribut (AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY), nama_atribut
Questions
Why isn't the insertion into tb_detailrusak executing as expected even when the conditions are met?
Are there any improvements or debugging steps I might be missing to resolve this issue?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

To be honest, I don't like the mixture of languages in your code. It makes it hard to read and understand. Sure, when communicating with the end user of your program you need to speak their language, but programmers, here on Stack Overflow, use English. $koneksi->close();, just looks weird to me, when you can use $connection->close(); as well. I have nothing against non-English languages, I'm Dutch myself, it's just that I would also never write: $verbinding->close();, and expect other people to just cope with that.

Is there anything in your logs - for example, "Atribut not found" - which would tell you that your SELECT id_atribut FROM tb_atribut WHERE nama_atribut = ? isn't returning anything for a specific attribute? Are there any fatal errors, warnings or notices when you run your script? Also, I'd change this line: $id_atribut = $atribut['id_atribut']; to be like this $id_atribut = (int)$atribut['id_atribut'];, since you're originally returning a string from your database, and later on you're binding it like an integer - $stmt_detail->bind_param(...).
